# Spring Data MongoDB @Indexed annotation - create index error (system.indexes) during find query operation

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am facing a weird issue as this has been working earlier with no issues.

I am using latest Spring Data MongoDB 1.5.2 release with Mongo Java Driver 2.12.3

I have used mongoDB ensureIndex command to create index on a collection field manaully through Mongo Shell (MongoDB serevr running with MongoDB 2.4 version).

I have checked both on my collection with collection.getIndexes() command and system.indexes collection too that the above index is created correctly.

With Spring Data MongoDB, I have also placed @Indexed annotation on same field in domain object.

During a query find operation, I was getting below Spring Data MongoDB create index exception for creating index in system.indexes collection and complained the document obj size is greater then 16MB.

If, I remove @Indexed annotation on domain object field and re-run the find query, then there are no errors from application side.

I would like to understand as why:

1) Spring Data MongoDB is trying to create index in system.indexes during a find query operation with @Indexed annotation available.

2) Why Spring Data MongoDB complains obj size is greater then 16 MB during find query operation with @Indexed annotation, whereas I can run the same find query on MongoDB shell with no issues.

3) Is the above document in collection is corrupt? Do I have to re-import fresh data again and test the same as this has been working in the past with no issues from application side?

4) What is the life cycle of Spring Data MongoDB @Indexed annotation or How does it works? Do we have any documentation available in details?

```
Domain Object

@Document(collection = "Users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

@Id
ObjectId id;

@Indexed
String appUserId

String firstName;

String lastName;

}

@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends MongoRepository<Users, String>, UsersRepositoryCustom {

// default query methods
}

@Repository
public interface UsersRepositoryCustom {
    int findUserCount(String appUserId);
}

@Component
public class UsersRepositoryImpl implements UsersRepositoryCustom {

@Override
    public int findUserCount(String appUserId) {

        DBCursor dbCursor = null;
        int count = 0;
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(
                Criteria.where("appUserId").is(appUserId));

        try {
            DBCollection dbCollection = mongoOperations.getCollection("Users");

            System.out.println("Start time : " + new Date().toString());
            dbCursor = dbCollection.find(query.getQueryObject());
            //while (dbCursor.hasNext()) {
              //do dome processing
            }
            count = dbCursor.count();
            System.out.println("End time : " + new Date().toString());
        } finally {
            dbCursor.close();
        }
        return count;


    }
}

Caused by: com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: { "serverUsed" : "XXXXXXXX:11111" , "err" : "BSONObj size: 0 (0x00000000) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: EOO" , "code" : 10334 , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 341 , "ok" : 1.0}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getWriteException(CommandResult.java:90)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$000(DBTCPConnector.java:39)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$1.execute(DBTCPConnector.java:186)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$1.execute(DBTCPConnector.java:181)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.doOperation(DBTCPConnector.java:210)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:181)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insertWithWriteProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:530)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.createIndex(DBCollectionImpl.java:369)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:564)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.createIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForAndCreateIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:46)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:181)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.`enter code here`RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
```

Comment: did you already run the according `db.collection.ensureIndex(keys, options)` command? The cause might be in the data you already have.

Comment: @Christoph - Thanks for your response. Looks like it was a data corrupt issue. The index were good.